# How to use Canny Edge Detection in OpenCV with keeping the colored image? Python

Tags: python, opencv

So I am trying to outline a blue colored box with a white line using Canny Edge Detection. It's just a black background with a blue square in the middle of the screen. This is the code I currently have:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('BlueSquare.png',0)
edges = cv.Canny(img,100,200)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'Blues')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'bone')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

I want my code to show the original image next to the same image but outlined in white.

The code ends up giving me a different original image. It changes the background from black to a light blue and the blue square to a different blue. Also, the second outline image is just all black with no outline or any blue square. I know that CV is in BGR format and matplot is in RGB I was going to change the values after the fact I just want to get it working with the ouline first. Anyone know how I can fix this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through the code, basically, you are loading the image in grayscale as you are passing '0', "img = cv.imread('BlueSquare.png',0)" with the image name which means now you don't have the original image so what I did is load the original image and then convert into the grayscale as the canny function takes a grayscale image as input. After that before passing the original image to plt.show(), I have converted it to RGB from BGR. Moreover, the canny image is being shown properly, let me attach my results.

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('Brand.jpeg')
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv.Canny(gray,100,200)

im_rgb = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(im_rgb,cmap = 'Blues')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'bone')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding. Ok I see how you fixed the issue of the original picture and actually getting the outline thank you for that. But do you know a way you can get the second image to be the original color but outlined? Like can you somehow map the outline back onto the original? Thank you

Comment: Also for some reason it outlines everything except blue.

Comment: Glad to know that I could help. For the next step, you will have to make contours out of those edges and then draw those contours on the source image. I am attaching a link here so that you can get an idea and try it by yourself. In case you are unable to do it, let me know and I will complete the code. Happy learning :)

https://dontrepeatyourself.org/post/edge-and-contour-detection-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: Regarding the blue outlines, it is coming from "cmap = 'bone'". try "cmap ='gray'" and see the results. I would suggest playing around with code for better leaning and looking into documentation.

Comment: Appreciate your help thank you